# .NET HttpListener/HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse and HTTPS

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have made a simple proxy using HttpListener and HttpWebRequest/Response to edit and log http headers. Everything works fine and dandy over HTTP but HTTPS is a different story, I have read up on MSDN and its says HttpListener & HttpWebRequest/Response works over HTTPS. Obviously its me doing something wrong.

I have IE pointed to the prefixes below and I cant seem to catch the request.

```
string[] prefixes = new string[] { "http://127.0.0.11:8080/", "https://127.0.0.12:8081/" };

HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
// Add the prefixes.
foreach (string s in prefixes)
{
    _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
}
```

Examples welcome and I'm a c# newb! :)

Answer (score 2):

https:// cannot be proxied like this. HTTPS (as in [RFC2818](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt)) uses SSL/TLS to open a secure tunnel that traverses the proxy. As a proxy, you don't have access to the HTTPS content because is going to be just an opaque binary encrypted goop.

What you expect is more like SHTTP ([RFC2660](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2660.txt)) which is used by basically nobody.

If you want to view HTTPS traffic originating on your machine (eg. for debugging purposes) you can use [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en). However, a proxy that could inspect all traffic going through it from other machines if by definition impossible to do for HTTPS, it would mean you just succeeded a man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Cylon Cat said, there is also [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore), which is the Fiddler proxy but in a form that you can use in your own application.  It supports HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy to do with the .NET framework.  If what you are wanting to do is write a man-in-the-middle proxy, like fiddler.  Then you can do it easily with SSLStream.  A client using your proxy will get a warning about an invalid SSL cert, but you can still proxy the traffic and inspect it.

Here is a pretty functional (includes caching!) proxy server that does https termination instead of tunneling (man-in-the-middle).  CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/HTTPSDebuggingProxy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're looking for, take a look at [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is a widely used proxy for web debugging. It does handle HTTPS.